# Plotting across the anti-meridian in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wonder if there are any packages which allow to plot across the anti-meridian in R yet?

I have location data I want to plot that moves across the line from west to east: 172 east to -172 west. (From 172 east, to 180 (anti-meridian) then onwards from -180 west to -172 west).

Previously I have had to plot this is two separate ggplots and then manually cut and paste them together, of course the two map halves don't merge / line up properly. It's also a pain in the butt to do this for every plot that crosses the line.

I'm using ggplot2, with ggOceanMaps for bathymetry.

```
# Create the longitude for left half
m_track$Lon_daily_east <- ifelse(m_track$Lon_daily_new < 0, 
                                 m_track$Lon_daily_new + 360, 
                                 m_track$Lon_daily_new)

# Create the longitude for right half
m_track$Lon_daily_west <- ifelse(m_track$Lon_daily_new > 0, 
                                 m_track$Lon_daily_new - 360, 
                                 m_track$Lon_daily_new)

left <- basemap(limits = c(172.0, 180, -40.0, -15.0), bathymetry = TRUE, legends = FALSE) +
  geom_point(data= m_track, aes(x = Lon_daily_east, y= Lat_daily_new, colour = tf), group = 1, size = 1.4) +
  geom_path(data = m_track, aes(x = Lon_daily_east, y= Lat_daily_new, colour = tf), group = 1, linewidth = 1.2)+
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Longitude")+
  ylab("Latitude")+
  labs(colour = "Days Elapsed")+
  coord_sf(xlim = c(172.0, 180), ylim = c(-40.0, -15.0), expand = FALSE)+
  theme(legend.position = "NULL",
    plot.margin = margin(t = 25.5, r = 0, b = 25.5, l = 0, unit = "pt")
    )

right <- basemap(limits = c(-180.00, -172, -40.0, -15.0), bathymetry = TRUE, legends = FALSE) +
  geom_point(data= m_track, aes(x = Lon_daily_west, y= Lat_daily_new, colour = tf), group = 1, size = 1.4) +
  geom_path(data = m_track, aes(x = Lon_daily_west, y= Lat_daily_new, colour = tf), group = 1, linewidth = 1.2)+
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Longitude")+
  ylab("Latitude")+
  labs(colour = "Days Elapsed")+
  theme(
    legend.text = element_text(size = 7),             # Legend text
    legend.title = element_text(size = 7),
    legend.justification = c("right","bottom"),
    legend.position = c(.52, .05),
    plot.margin = margin(t = 25.5, r = 0, b = 25.5, l = 0, unit = "pt")
  )
```

example data:

```
         Date Lon_daily_new Lat_daily_new tf month_d data_group Lon_daily_east Lon_daily_west
34 2019-04-08       177.950       -26.625 34   April          1        177.950       -182.050
35 2019-04-09       178.325       -26.175 35   April          1        178.325       -181.675
36 2019-04-10       178.675       -25.850 36   April          1        178.675       -181.325
37 2019-04-11       179.075       -25.550 37   April          1        179.075       -180.925
38 2019-04-12       179.350       -25.250 38   April          1        179.350       -180.650
39 2019-04-13      -179.925       -24.825 39   April          1        180.075       -179.925
40 2019-04-14      -179.425       -24.275 40   April          1        180.575       -179.425
41 2019-04-15      -179.425       -23.700 41   April          1        180.575       -179.425
42 2019-04-16      -179.375       -23.125 42   April          1        180.625       -179.375
43 2019-04-17      -179.200       -22.750 43   April          1        180.800       -179.200
```

example crop of a plot cut together manually
[image: example plot across anti-meridian cut together manually]

Comment: According to this closed issue https://github.com/MikkoVihtakari/ggOceanMaps/issues/28, antimeridian plotting should just work.  (You may need to use the Github version of ggOceanMaps).  If it doesn't work for you, you should post a new issue there, including reproducible code to show the problem.

Comment: Aside from the referenced bugfix, why are you making two separate plots instead of two grobs in the same plot window with the same axis coordinate system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user2554330 Thanks, you are correct. The package has been updated, and in version 2 it is now possible to plot across the anti-meridian.
Get the latest version with

```
remotes::install_github("MikkoVihtakari/ggOceanMaps")
```

The ggplot functions geom_path and geom_point don't work without using transform_coord() but that means changing the format of my data frame a lot, using ggspatial instead allows me to use the existing data frame and colour.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggOceanMaps)
library(ggspatial)

basemap(limits = c(172, -178, -25, -15), 
        rotate = TRUE,
        lat.interval = 5,
        lon.interval = 2,
        bathy.style = "rbb", # default choice, or use "rcb" for continuous bathy
        legends = FALSE) +
  ggspatial::geom_spatial_point(data= m_track, aes(x = Lon_daily_new, y= Lat_daily_new, colour = tf), group = 1, size = 1.4) +
  ggspatial::geom_spatial_path(data = m_track, aes(x = Lon_daily_new, y= Lat_daily_new, colour = tf), group = 1, linewidth = 1.2)+
  theme_bw() 
...
```

coord_sf with x axis limits is not compatible with rotate = TRUE, it doesn't matter whether the map crosses the anti-meridian or not.
From Mikko (ggOceanMaps dev):
'The reason why coord_sf() does not work is because rotate modifies the CRS. To make it work, you'll need to take the CRS from the basemap object:

```
p <-basemap(limits = c(172, -176, -40, -15))
p + coord_sf(xlim = attributes(p)$limits[c("xmin", "xmax")], ylim = c(-40, -15), expand = FALSE, crs = attributes(p)$crs)
```

Comment: There was a windows only issue using any non-default bathymetry such as "rcb", which had to download the file. It has now been fixed and CRAN updated with the latest package